# Why does return statement and print statement return different answers?

Tags: c++

The problem I am having is why does returning greatestProduct and printing greatestProduct output different results. The former answer is wrong and the latter is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int largestproduct();
int main() {
cout << largestproduct() << endl;
}

int largestproduct()
{
const int adjacentDigits = 13;
int n = 0;
unsigned long greatestProduct = 0;
signed char num[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

while(n <= 1000-adjacentDigits)
{
    unsigned long product = 1;
    for(int i = n; i < n+adjacentDigits;i++)
    {
        product *= (num[i] - '0');
    }

    if(greatestProduct < product)
    {
        greatestProduct = product;
    }
    n++;

}
cout << greatestProduct << endl; //the problem is right here!!!
return greatestProduct;
}
```

Comment: You're returning an  `unsigned long` from a function that returns `int`. There's an implicit conversion and a loss of precision happening.

Comment: The warning to enable is [-Wconversion]

Answer (score 5):

You need to change `int largestproduct()` to: `unsigned long largestproduct()`. Since you are losing precision due to an implicit conversion.

Comment: First and foremost OP needs to read compiler warnings (and enable them if they are not already)